# Compare 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

is there a function to compare 2 different associative arrays, and return changes?

For example

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"");
$age2 = array("Peter"=>"38","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");
```

return

```
$return = array(
    "Peter"=>"Changed from 35 to 38",
    "Joe"=>"Changed from blank to 43"
);
```

Comment: Nothing that return a result like what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out before, `array_diff_assoc` is your starting point. The rest is building your strings for each difference:

```
function compareAge($age, $age2)
{
    $return = array();
    foreach(array_keys(array_diff_assoc($age, $age2)) as $diffKey) {
        $from = empty($age[$diffKey]) ? 'blank' : $age[$diffKey];
        $to = empty($age2[$diffKey]) ? 'blank' : $age2[$diffKey];
        $return[$diffKey] = "Changed from {$from} to {$to}";
    }
    return $return;
}
```

**[working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5bb7ebf7035537c27f87d3c8634ed3937f05aa0)**

Comment: this works great, is there a way to include names as well ex. `Joe changed from 20 to empty`?

Comment: Within the loop, "Joe" would be in `$diffKey`, so: yes.

Answer (score 5):

[array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) may start you on the right path. Although it doesn't give the exact output you're looking for, it will show you the differences between two arrays.

As mark pointed out, [array_diff_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) may be even more helpful as it maintains array indexes.

Comment: array_diff_assoc() might be even more useful

Answer (score 1):

Nothing default, by I had some time on my hands :) http://codepad.org/2UtrPE3o

```
<?
$age = array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"");
$age2 = array("Peter"=>"38","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");

$result = array();
foreach($age as $key=>$val) {
  if (array_key_exists($key, $age2)) {
    if ($val!==$age2[$key])
      $result[$key] = 'Changed from '.(empty($val)?'blank':$val).' to '. (empty($age2[$key])?'blank':$age2[$key]);
  } else {
    $result[$key] = 'Changed from '.(empty($val)?'blank':$val).' to blank';
  }
}

foreach($age2 as $key=>$val) {
  if (!array_key_exists($key, $age)) {
    $result[$key] = 'Changed from blank to ' . $val;
  }
}

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this, more efficient solution :

```
$age1   = array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"");
$age2   = array("Peter"=>"38","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");

$result = array_diff_assoc($age1, $age2);

$res    = array();
foreach($result as $key=>$val){
  $res[$key]  = "Changed from ".($val?$val:"Balnk")." to ".($age2[$key]?$age2[$key]:"blank");
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```